# I want to pre answer the csr questions can someone show me how to do this?

Tags: openssl, headless

I'm trying to make an easy bake ssl certificate generation script.  The problem is I don't know how to create something like an answer sheet for creating the CSR.

rndpass=$(REDACTED) && openssl genrsa -passout pass:$rndpass -aes256 4096 > server.key && echo $rndpass > server.key.pass && openssl req -sha256 -passin pass:$rndpass -new -key /root/server.key -out server.csr

Answer (score 1):

After much more digging I managed to find a way to make this happen.

```
RNDPASS=$(REDACTED) && openssl genrsa -passout pass:$RNDPASS -aes256 4096 > server.key && echo $rndpass > server.key.pass && openssl req -sha256 -passin pass:$RNDPASS -subj "/C=US/ST=Denial/L=Springfield/O=Dis/CN=example.com" -new -key server.key -out server.csr
```

I grabbed my answer from [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/155969/openssl-certificate-generation-commands)

This is the output results of me running this line.  I'm certainly not suggesting to anyone that they actually use this certificate csr or password.

> root@21944aa49917:~# cat server.csr |gist-paste -p
>   https://gist.github.com/2f90234c701ec2244365 root@21944aa49917:~# cat
>   server.key |gist-paste -p https://gist.github.com/bf508e9048e2e4a385d3
>   root@21944aa49917:~# cat server.key.pass |gist-paste -p
>   https://gist.github.com/2cd73181136895133621

Breaking this down a bit.

First we need to generate a random password that we will store in the variable $RNDPASS for the sake of my security I will not be disclosing what magic I use to create my string but it outputs a 32 character string.

> RNDPASS=$([REDACTED](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/30184/10-ways-to-generate-a-random-password-from-the-command-line/)) &&

Then we need to generate the key giving it the password with the poorly manpaged "-passout ARG" portion of "openssl genrsa" you can read more [here.](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/openssl.html)

> openssl genrsa -passout pass:$RNDPASS -aes256 4096 > server.key &&

Now that we have a key generated and things didn't fail lets store the output in server.key.pass.  You could really pipe this anywhere even just back to stdout I choose to stick it into a file in this example with...

> echo $rndpass > server.key.pass &&

Finally we need to generate the csr (Certificate Sign Request) this should be populated with environment variables if you wanted you could use this with docker and environment variables to auto-generate an ssl cert this way.

> openssl req -sha256 -passin pass:$RNDPASS -subj > "/C=US/ST=Denial/L=Springfield/O=Dis/CN=example.com" -new -key server.key -out server.csr

Comment: `CN=www.example.com` - You should visit your site with Chrome. Its sure to fail. ***DO NOT*** put DNS names in the CN. Its deprecated by both the IETF and CA/B Forums. Put DNS names in the SAN.

Comment: @jww you happen to know the short version for each of the key details?

Comment: I wish that I saw this earlier but sadly I don't.  If you did figure them out please feel free to post them I'm sure the future internet landing on this will love to know.